# get value of hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, input

I reference the hidden field like:

```
var h = document.getElementById('myHiddenField');
```

How can I set the value to 100, and then output the value using a simple alert();?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817041/jquery-to-get-hidden-field-value for a jQuery approach

Answer (score 21):

```
var h = document.getElementById('myHiddenField');
h.value = 100;
alert(h.value);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
//get value
var hidderValue = document.getElementById('myHiddenField').value;

//set value
document.getElementById('myHiddenField').value = 200;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `value` property of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to set hidden field's value IN the html part.
To do so write:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" value="100"></input>
```