# jQuery to get Hidden Field Value in Table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have a table with a hidden field in each row. I need to Alert the value of hidden field when a button in that row is clicked. I have the following jQuery code. But it does not work. How do we make it work?

CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/xWanB/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //"Show ID" for Associate Button Click
        $('.resultGridTable tr > td > .actionButtonNational').click(function () {
            //"this" means show ID button
            //Traversing to get the parent row and then the required columns in the row
            var associateID = $(this).parents('tr:first > .wrapperDivHidden input[type=hidden]').val();
            alert(associateID);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<td>
    XXXXX
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdSubscribedAssociates$ctl04$btnNational"
                        value="Show ID" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdSubscribedAssociates_btnNational_2"
                        class="actionButtonNational" style="color: White; background-color: #A7A7A6;
                        font-weight: bold; width: 60px" />
    <div id="wrapperDivHidden" class="wrapperDivHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdSubscribedAssociates$ctl04$hdnAssociateID"
                            id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdSubscribedAssociates_hdnAssociateID_2"value="789345680" />
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

your selector starts with `tr:first > .wrapperDivHidden ...` but `.wrapperDivHidden` is not an immediate child of `tr` so change your selector like so:

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('.wrapperDivHidden input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xWanB/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //"Show ID" for Associate Button Click
        $('.actionButtonNational').click(function () {
            var associateID = $('input[type=hidden]', $(this).closest("td")).val();
            alert(associateID);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an over simplified example of what you are trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/6S5rD/

Comment: I am working with ASP.Net HiddenField. Hence it may nit work for me.

Answer (score 0):

if the first column of your row is hidden then use this
var x = $('input[type=hidden]', $(this).find("td:first")).val();