# Find rows in a table where hidden field has value

Tags: jquery

I have a table where every row has a hidden control as shown below

```
<input name="ID" id="ID" type="hidden"/>
```

But some of them have values and others don't. How do I filter out the rows that have no value

I know it would be something like

```
$('#myTable tr').filter(... ???
```

What I am trying to do is, get the rows where the hidden control has a value, then fetch certain controls and their values from those rows and post them using jquery ajax.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817041/jquery-to-get-hidden-field-value-in-table-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of João's answer, to get the row you just need to take his second option and traverse up to the parent.

`$('#myTable tr input[type="hidden"][value!=""]').parent();`

That is assuming the hidden input is a direct descendent of the `<tr>`. Otherwise you may want to use the jQuery [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) function like so:

`$('#myTable tr input[type="hidden"][value!=""]').parents('tr');`

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
$('#myTable tr').filter(function () {
  return $(this).find('input[type="hidden"][value!=""]').length;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vrn96/)**.

Comment: That fetches the hidden control. I want the entire row :(

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to it:

```
<input name="ID" id="ID" type="hidden" class="someclass" />

$('#myTable tr .someclass').doSomething(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

the selector `'input[value]'` selects all inputs having a value attribute.

```
$("#myTable input[value], #myTable input[value!='']").doSomthing(...);
```