# HiddenField aspx from TableRow

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-table

I have the following setup currently:

```
<tr class="NoBackgroundTR">
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Adresse").ToString() %>' ></asp:HiddenField></td>
</tr>
```

This would be pretty much be the code I would want to write:

```
function setBGColor()
    {
        var table = document.getElementById("AlleAnzeigenTable");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            // here I would like to get the HiddenField inside of my TableRow
            if(row.HiddenField.value != 'someValue')
                row.style.backgroundColor = '#F79A03';
        }
    }
```

How would I access the Hiddenfield inside of my TableRow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817041/jquery-to-get-hidden-field-value-in-table-row

Comment: Is this directly in row or in td ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad If you mean the Structure of my Table it is <table><tr><HiddenField /></tr></table> if i use the code recommended by Iti I get undefined as return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can access it like this:

```
var myHiddenField = $(row).find('input[type="hidden"]');
var value = myHiddenField.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have hidden field as very first control you can use below code.

But i would recommend to use an `ID` or `ClassName` in order to `access` the `HiddenFeild` inside `row`.

```
var table = document.getElementById("AlleAnzeigenTable");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    var value = row.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
}
```